# Making a short alias for document.querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, native-methods

I'm running `document.querySelectorAll()` frequently, and would like a short alias for it.

```
var queryAll = document.querySelectorAll

queryAll('body')
TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Doesn't work. Whereas:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body')
```

Still does. How can I make the alias work?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
const queryAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
```

`bind` returns a new function which works identically to the `querySelectorAll` function, where the value of `this` inside the `querySelectorAll` method is bound to the `document` object.

The bind function is only supported in IE9+ (and all the other browsers) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

---

**Update:** In fact you could create shortcuts to a whole range of document methods like this:

```
const query = document.querySelector.bind(document);
const queryAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
const fromId = document.getElementById.bind(document);
const fromClass = document.getElementsByClassName.bind(document);
const fromTag = document.getElementsByTagName.bind(document);
```

Comment: Is there an ES6 module that does that and takes your element as a base?

Comment: The bound function queryAll is what is known in ES6 as an *exotic function object* (term from ECMAScript 6). The link has some good examples... it should be said that there is a group of people who go by *The Good Parts*  and strongly advise against doing "this" juggling in your own code, it gets confusing quickly.

Comment: The one for `getElementById` is not necessary since an alias already exists and it's the id itself (eg. `myid.innerHTML` is equal to `document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML`)

Comment: Note that while `bind` is supported in IE9, `const` is only supported from IE11, and not fully. See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations. Thankfully, nobody cares anymore.

Comment: I have found this particularly useful: `const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document); 
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);`.

Comment: @Manngo glad you find this particularly useful. Dont forget to upvote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46079132/1248177

Answer (score 38):

A common answer is to use `$` and `$$` for `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`. This alias mimics jQuery's one.

Example:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)

$('div').style.color = 'blue'
$$('div').forEach(div => div.style.background = 'orange')
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  test
</div>
<section>
  <div>
    hello
  </div>
  <div>
    foo
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 15):

The JavaScript interpreter throws an error because `querySelectorAll()` should be invoked in document context.

The same error is thrown when you are trying to call `console.log()` aliased.

So you need to wrap it like this:

```
 function x(selector) {
     return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
 }
```

Comment: Had issues with some libs and the bind example re: document context conflict whereas this always seems to work...

Answer (score 11):

My solution covers the four following use cases:

- document.querySelector(...)
- document.querySelectorAll(...)
- element.querySelector(...)
- element.querySelectorAll(...)

The code:

```
let doc=document,
    qsa=(s,o=doc)=>o.querySelectorAll(s),
    qs=(s,o=doc)=>o.querySelector(s);
```

In terms of parameters, the selector `s` is required, but the container element object `o` is optional.

Usage:

- `qs("div")`: Queries the whole document for the first div, returns that element
- `qsa("div")`: Queries the whole document for all divs, returns a nodeList of all those elements
- `qs("div", myContainer)`: Queries just within the myContainer element for the first div, returns that element
- `qsa("div", myContainer)`: Queries just within the myContainer element for all divs, returns a nodeList of all those elements

To make the code slightly shorter (but not quite as efficient), the `qs` code could be written as follows:

```
let qs=(s,o=doc)=>qsa(s,o)[0];
```

The code above uses ES6 features (`let`, arrow functions and default parameter values). An ES5 equivalent is:

```
var doc=document,
    qsa=function(s,o){return(o||doc).querySelectorAll(s);},
    qs=function(s,o){return(o||doc).querySelector(s);};
```

or the equivalent shorter but less efficient ES5 version of `qs`:

```
var qs=function(s,o){return qsa(s,o)[0];};
```

Below is a working demo. To ensure it works on all browsers, it uses the ES5 version, but if you're going to use this idea, remember that the ES6 version is shorter:

```js
var doc = document;

var qs=function(s,o){return(o||doc).querySelector(s);},
    qsa=function(s,o){return(o||doc).querySelectorAll(s);}

var show=function(s){doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("p")).innerHTML=s;}

//           ____demo____       _____long equivalent______      __check return___      _expect__ 
//          |            |     |                          |    |                 |    |         |

let one   = qs("div");      /* doc.querySelector   ("#one") */ show(one  .id    ); // "one"
let oneN  = qs("div",one);  /* one.querySelector   ("div")  */ show(oneN .id    ); // "oneNested"
let many  = qsa("div");     /* doc.querySelectorAll("div")  */ show(many .length); // 3
let manyN = qsa("div",one); /* one.querySelectorAll("div")  */ show(manyN.length); // 2
```

```html
<h3>Expecting "one", "oneNested", 3 and 2...</h3>
<div id="one">
  <div id="oneNested"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific reason you use `let` instead of `const`? And you could use `$qsa` and `$qs`, so DOM elements can still be prefixed with `$` - but that's just an idea.

Answer (score 7):

This would work, you need to invoke the alias using `call()` or `apply()` with the appropriate context.

```
func.call(context, arg1, arg2, ...) 
func.apply(context, [args]) 

var x = document.querySelectorAll;
x.call(document, 'body');
x.apply(document, ['body']);
```

Comment: +1 - Interesting approach since the real issue with `x('body')` is that it's missing the `this` context.

Answer (score 6):

I took @David Muller's approach and one-lined it using a lambda

```
let $ = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
let $all = (selector) => document.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

Example:

```
$('body');
// <body>...</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function x(expr)
{
    return document.querySelectorAll(expr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about supporting ancient, awful browsers that nobody should be using anymore, then you can just do this:

```js
const $ = (sel, parent = document) => parent.querySelector(sel);
const $$ = (sel, parent = document) => Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll(sel));
```

Here's some examples of usage:

```
// find specific element by id
console.log($("#someid"));
// find every element by class, within other element
// NOTE: This is a contrived example to demonstrate the parent search feature.
// If you don't already have the parent in a JavaScript variable, you should
// query via $$("#someparent .someclass") for better performance instead.
console.log($$(".someclass", $("#someparent")));
// find every h1 element
console.log($$("h1"));
// find every h1 element, within other element
console.log($$("h1", $("#exampleparent")));
// alternative way of finding every h1 element within other element
console.log($$("#exampleparent h1"));
// example of finding an element and then checking if it contains another element
console.log($("#exampleparent").contains($("#otherelement")));
// example of finding a bunch of elements and then further filtering them by criteria
// that aren't supported by pure CSS, such as their text content
// NOTE: There WAS a ":contains(text)" selector in CSS3 but it was deprecated from the
// spec because it violated the separation between stylesheets and text content, and you
// can't rely on that CSS selector, which is why you should never use it and should
// instead re-implement it yourself like we do in this example.
// ALSO NOTE: This is just a demonstration of .filter(). I don't recommend using
// "textContent" as a filter. If you need to find specific elements, use their way
// more reliable id/class to find them instead of some arbitrary text content search.
console.log($$("#exampleparent h1").filter(el => el.textContent === "Hello World!"));
```

The functions I provided use a ton of modern JS features:

- `const` to make sure the function variable can't be overwritten.
- functions defined as an arrow function aka lambda: `(args) => code with implied return statement`
- default parameters (not supported by browsers before the year 2016)
- no `{}` or `return`, since those can be skipped if there's just 1 statement in the function body.
- The modern function `Array.from()` is used, which converts the `querySelectorAll` result (which is always a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), or empty NodeList), into an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), which is basically what every developer wants. Because that's how you get access to `.filter()` and other Array functions that allow you to process the discovered nodes further, using clean, short code. And `Array.from()` creates a shallow copy of all elements which means that it's blazingly fast (it just copies the memory references/pointers to each [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) DOM element from the original NodeList). It's a major API enhancer.

If you care about ancient browsers, you can still use my functions but use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert the modern JS to old ES5 when you release your website.

My suggestion would be to write your entire site in ES6 or higher and then use Babel if you care about visitors from Windows XP and other dead operating systems, or just random people who haven't updated their browsers in 5+ years.

But I wouldn't recommend using Babel. Stop worrying about people who have old browsers. It is **their problem,** not yours.

The modern "app" world is incredibly deeply based on web browsers and JavaScript and modern CSS, and most of your visitors these days have modern, auto-updated browsers. You basically **can't** live modern life without a modern browser, since so many websites demand it now.

In my opinion, the days of expecting **web designers** to waste their time and sanity trying to make a site work on browsers from 1993 are **over.** It's time the **laziest customers/visitors** update their old browsers instead. It's not difficult. Even old and dead operating systems usually have ways to install new versions of browsers on them. And people who don't have an updated browser are only a tiny fraction of a percent these days.

For example, the Bootstrap framework, the world's most popular framework for mobile/responsive sites, **only** cares about supporting the 2 most recent major versions of all major browsers (at least 0.5% market share). Here's their list as of this moment:

- 0.5% market share or higher
- last 2 major versions only
- not a dead browser (not discontinued)
- Chrome >= 60
- Firefox >= 60
- Firefox ESR
- iOS >= 12
- Safari >= 12
- not Explorer <= 11 (meaning no versions of Internet Explorer at all)

And I completely agree with this. I was a web developer in the early 2000s and it was absolute hell. Being expected to make it work on some random, stupid user's ancient browser was hell. It took all the fun out of web development. It made me **hate** and **quit** web development. Because 90% of my time was wasted on browser compatibility. That's not how life should be. It's not your fault that some customers/visitors are **lazy.** And these days, visitors have no more excuses to stay lazy.

Instead, you should only target users who have modern browsers. Which is basically everybody these days. There is no excuse for anyone to use an old browser. And if they use an old browser, your site should show a big, fat banner saying "Please, join the modern world for your own sake. Download a new browser. How are you even able to live your normal life with such an old browser? Are you a time traveler from caveman times?".

People have **no excuses** to have old browsers anymore:

1. Linux: Ships with the latest versions of Firefox by default.
2. Mac: Ships with Safari, which is a modern browser. But some older macOS versions won't get newer versions of Safari, and older machines often can't install the latest macOS version either. Well, tough luck for those visitors. They are gonna have trouble on more than just your website. It's up to them to install a modern browser (such as Chrome), which they are able to do even on old versions of macOS. So they have no excuses. Don't waste your life catering to people on very old, buggy Safari versions.
3. Windows: Windows 10 ships with Edge, which is based on Chromium and is as compatible with websites as Chrome is. People have no excuse to have an old browser. And most Windows users use Chrome. As for very old, discontinued versions of Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8), well, we yet again arrive at the same question as before: Do you care about 0.0000001% stupid visitors who use a dead OS and an old Internet Explorer version? The whole freaking web will be broken for them anyway, so who cares if your site is broken for them **too?** They should stop being lazy and just upgrade their OS to Windows 10, or at least install Chrome or Firefox on their current OS. They have no excuses.
4. iOS: If you're stuck on a super old iOS device, then you can't use the modern web. Tough luck. A lot of the web is gonna be broken for you. Get a new device. Even frameworks like Bootstrap, the world's #1 mobile web framework, doesn't support iOS 11 or earlier. It's not our problem. It's the cheapskate visitor's problem if they still hang onto such an old device. They can literally get a newer iOS device second-hand for almost no money at all and fix all of their problems with visiting the modern web. And they'll need to buy that anyway since most apps (even banking/important apps) require modern iOS versions.
5. Android: The browser is independently updated from the OS, and can even be sideloaded, so even if you're stuck on old Android versions, you have access to modern browsers. So you have no excuses.

Most people these days have browsers that are completely up-to-date and auto-updated. That's the fact.

So yeah... the days of website designers suffering through hell just for catering to old browsers are over. Therefore I suggest that people use ES6 and CSS3 for their websites, to make web designing a joy for the first time.

Hope you enjoy the ES6 functions I provided!

Comment: I take it you don't like old browsers. Just a friendly reminder that people come here for answers, not blog posts.

Comment: @thordarson Yeah. And anyone who uses any of the answers here will need to know the things my blog post mentions. ;-) Because anyone who custom-codes JavaScript instead of using libraries like jQuery will be in ES6-territory very quickly.

Comment: I do get your pain with catering to older browsers and all that, I've been there. I'm just not sure that's even in the minds of people with the dominance of Webkit and Chromium based browsers (except maybe some unlucky legacy developers) and your solution is effectively the same as in [this 5 year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35695073/2005939).

Comment: @thordarson Ah, another war veteran from the old web dev days. I'm returning to web development and still see most people talk about compatibility. But when doing things like these custom functions instead of jQuery, you lose compatibility with old browsers, so people need to be aware of that. We'll see whether the voters will appreciate or downvote this answer. As for the older answer you linked to, it's really messy and doesn't provide modern `Array` syntax (re-read the top of my answer and notice the `Array.from()`). :-) Anyway comments aren't for extended discussions so take care man. 

Comment: **Totally support and agree with the sentiment towards old browsers.** This post could be improved by removing 'crap' and 'screw' and all caps, and replacing the quoted stats with links.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I replaced uppercase words with bold instead, and softened some of the words. Take care. 

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on it. If the selector has multiple matches, return like `querySelectorAll`. If ony one match is found return like `querySelector`.

```
function $(selector) {
  let all = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  if(all.length == 1) return all[0];
  return all;
}

let one = $('#my-single-element');
let many = $('#multiple-elements li');
```

**2019 update**

Today I made a new take on the problem. In this version you can also use a base like this:

```php
let base = document.querySelectorAll('ul');

$$('li'); // All li
$$('li', base); // All li within ul
```

**Functions**

```php
function $(selector, base = null) {
  base = (base === null) ? document : base;
  return base.querySelector(selector);
}

function $$(selector, base = null) {
  base = (base === null) ? document : base;
  return base.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Comment: Your original function would be a mess to work with if it ever turned 1 result when 0 or 2+ were expected, or returned 0/2+ when one was expected.

Answer (score 1):

The highly invasive version:

```html
<script>
    for(const c of [HTMLDocument, Element, DocumentFragment]) {
      c.prototype.$ = c.prototype.querySelector;
      c.prototype.$$ = c.prototype.querySelectorAll;
    }
    const $ = document.$.bind(document); // For inline events
    const $$ = document.$$.bind(document);
    window.$ = $; // For JS files
    window.$$ = $$;
</script>
```

So you can chain `$('nav').$$('a')` like jQuery allows (I think). Since `ShadowRoot` extends `DocumentFragment` you can even inspect (open) Shadow DOMs:

```js
const styles = $('x-button').shadowRoot.$$('style');
```

---

Comment: Hah brilliant. I wouldn't use this but props for style! 

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function $(selector, base = null) {
>   base = (base === null) ? document : base;
>   return base.querySelector(selector);
> }
>
> function $$(selector, base = null) {
>   base = (base === null) ? document : base;
>   return base.querySelectorAll(selector);
> }
> ```

Why not simplier ??? :

```
let $ = (selector, base = document) => {
  let elements = base.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return (elements.length == 1) ? elements[0] : elements;
}
```

Comment: Probably because you'd get a NodeList or Element depending on how many results there are.

Comment: Yes. Compare the `result.constructor.name` for 1 result vs many.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add any dot before class name you can modify this also by using getEle by class or id tag etc

```
    function $(selector){
        var dot = ".";
      var newSelector = dot.concat(selector);
      var Check = document.querySelectorAll(newSelector);
      if(Check && Check.length>0 && Check.length < 2){
        return document.querySelector(newSelector);
      }
      else {
        return document.querySelectorAll(newSelector);
      }
     
}

$("answercell")[0].remove();
```

Comment: Hi Gopal! Good idea to include the dot for you if you only ever want to pick elements by class. However 'querySelectorAll` can select on more than just class name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).