# What is the meaning of document.querySelector.bind(document);

Tags: javascript, bind, document, parallax.js

I was checking this code from html5rocks:
http://www.html5rocks.com/static/demos/parallax/demo-1a/scripts/parallax.js

And notice that they use

```
(function(win, d) {

  var $ = d.querySelector.bind(d);

  ....

  var mainBG = $('section#content');

  ....

})(window, document);
```

Why they bind the document to the querySelector. Isn't it already scoped to the document?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383886/making-a-short-alias-for-document-queryselectorall) has further explanation.  Short answer: JavaScript interpreter throws an error because querySelectorAll() should be invoked in document context.

Answer (score 4):

No, [the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) is not bound to a specific document (there may be other ones, not just `window.document`). Try it without, and you will get an `WRONG_THIS_ERR` exception - you will need to apply it on an object that implements the [`Document` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#interface-definitions).

Also have a look on [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on how the `thisVal`("context") of a function call is determined.

Comment: Thank you.

Let's assume we are not in "strict mode", in a browser, and we create a function:

    `function a() {
      console.log(this);
    }`

if we call

    `a();`

the console print `window`.   But it is like javascript prepend `this.` behind the scene `this.a();` and this is the window context.  For the same reason if we create a new object `var o = {};` and we assign the a method `o.a = a;` and we run `o.a();` the console print the o object.  I know it might not be the proper explanation, but this "context" in javascript sometime is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers, and as a side note, one can also use `document.querySelector.bind(document)` to make jQuery-like selections:

```
var $$ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
console.log( $$('#answers').textContent );
```

```js
var $$ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
console.log( 'Ye Olde StackSnippet body: ', $$('body').textContent );
```